# Partition by date and dynamically generate the partition of the current date With DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

My current data directory is `/data/20220214` and `/data/20220215`. Below each date folder is a csv file and I want to partition them by date. For example, the `20220216` file should be placed under the new partition 20220216. Can anyone share some insight on how o achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose here you have a directory of DolphinDB DATE type. You can try `loadText()` to load files as in-memory tables. Then set `` t[`date]=dirName `` to keep the table schema.